# Bug with Windows/Windows Picture and Fax Viewer

Tags: windows

Recently I copied few photos from my digi cam to my laptop. And what i found was, in Thumbnail view, the Image preview on the photos are different from the actual file.

i.e consider if the Image preview on a file is image of a Forest, on Opening the file in Windows Fax viewer i get image of a Seashore(Both images of seashore and forest are present in that folder).

The Actual image is that of a seashore. But in image preview i'm getting different images.

How to get rid of this.? It is really annoying. I open a file expecting a image and it turns out to be a different image. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it'll be related with thumbs.db.  This file is a cache of the thumbnail pictures in a directory. You can [get rid of](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/98) this file for fixing.

Alternatively, you should use [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com) instead of that default windows picture viewer.

Comment: Thanks.. actually while copying the photos, i replaced the existing thumbs.db with the new thumbs.db.